# How do I access a prisma function from a component other than the page.server.js file in sveltekit?

Tags: prisma, sveltekit

I currently have a `+page.svelte` which I am passing the data retrieved from the `+page.server.js` into a card which is located in the `lib` folder. I also have a modal that is located in my `lib` folder which pops up a form to create/edit/delete a comment.

I am not sure how I can access the prisma create/edit/delete from the modal which is located inside the `lib` folder. I did try to import prisma in my modal component however I cannot do that as it will only load in a `page.server.js` file.

I'm not sure if this information is necessary but just in case:

`+page.svelte` has an area card located in `lib` folder
area card has modal backdrop located in `lib` folder
modal backdrop had modal also located in `lib` folder

modal backdrop is hidden unless a showmodal is true which I am setting in the store.

`+page.svelte`:

```html
<div class="{$showModalBackdrop ? '' : 'hidden'}  w-full h-full fixed top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 bg-black bg-opacity-60" on:click|self={closeModal}>
<ModalBackdrop  />
</div>
<div class="flex flex-col items-center text-black">
    {#each areas as area}
        <AreaCard {area} />
    {/each}
</div>
```

Modal located in lib:

```html
const handleSave = () => {
        if (author === '') {
            Swal.fire('Author cannot be empty');
        } else if (comment === '') {
            Swal.fire('Comment cannot be empty');
        } else {
            $modalAreaIdStore = 0;
            $showModalBackdrop = false;
            $refreshComments = !$refreshComments;
        }
    };

    const handleEdit = () => {
        console.log('Edite clicked');
        $modalAreaIdStore = 0;
        $showModalBackdrop = false;
        $refreshComments = !$refreshComments;
    };
    async function handleDelete(id) {
        $modalAreaIdStore = 0;
        $showModalBackdrop = false;
        $refreshComments = !$refreshComments;
    }

    $: $commentToEditStore, getComment();
    $: $showModalBackdrop, clearForm();
</script>


<div
    class="{$showAddComment
        ? ''
        : 'hidden'} fixed top-1/4 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 w-1/3 border-2 rounded-lg bg-slate-100 font-bold addCommentModal"
>
    <div class="m-4">
        <div class="text-lg pb-4 border-b-2">
            <h1>{$modalAreaIdStore != 0 ? 'Add Safety Item:' : 'Edit Safety Item:'}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <label for="author">Author</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                class="bg-slate-100 w-full rounded-lg p-2 outline outline-blue-500"
                bind:value={author}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="" for="comment">Comment</label>
            <textarea
                name="comment"
                id="comment"
                cols="22"
                rows="5"
                class="bg-slate-100 w-full border rounded-lg focus:border-white p-2"
                bind:value={comment}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <Dropzone on:drop={handleFilesSelect} />
            <ol>
                {#each files.accepted as item}
                    <li>{item.name}</li>
                    <li>{item.size}</li>
                {/each}
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div>
            {#if $modalAreaIdStore === 0}
                <button
                    class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded"
                    on:click={() => (showConfirmDeleteButton = true)}
                >
                    Delete
                </button>
                {#if showConfirmDeleteButton}
                    <button class="" on:click={() => handleDelete($commentToEditStore.entry_id)}>Confirm Delete</button>
                {/if}
            {/if}

            <div class="float-right">
                <button
                    class="m-2 bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
                    on:click={$modalCommentIdStore === 0 ? () => handleSave() : () => handleEdit()}
                >
                    Save
                </button>
                <button
                    class="m-2 bg-slate-300 hover:bg-slate-500 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
                    on:click={() => handleCancelButton()}
                >
                    Cancel
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can't. Reason is that `+page.svelte` is a client-side file. This means that this file will be run in the client (i.e. the browser). This means that this file, despite it is delivered from your server, it is run in a completely different computer so it does not have access to functions in your server. So what can you do? You can create an API (`+server.ts`) which runs in the server and then use `fetch` to pull the data from your `+page.svelte` file (or other svelte file). Alternatively, if possible, you can send the data on first load if it is safe and known.

Comment: So how do I call the function in the server file from the client file? In my server file I will have a method `async function getDepts = await.prisma.Depts.findmany()` in a +server.ts file, how do I call this function from the client side and use the data retrieved?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to figure it out with your help and with the docs https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server-receiving-data. I do have one more problem, I'm not sure how to reload the pagedata from the server on the +page.server.ts file which gets all comments after I make the call to add/delete function in the +server.js.

Comment: You can either reload the page (`location.reload()`) which will force the browser to request the `+page.server.ts` with the new data. Alternatively, you can return the new data as a response in the `+server.ts` so after making the request in your svelte file, you just need to get the data from the response and replace the previous instance with the new one.